# Get contents of appended html Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying get div element that was previously appended to bind click action on it.

this doesn't work

```
var link = linkList.append('<div>click me</div>');

link.find('div').click(function(){
        alert("I'm here");
        return false;
        });
```

Comment: What is `linkList`? And do you see any errors in your console?

Comment: Works just fine for me: **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6BeWv/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) so that it will return the newly added element

```
var link = $('<div>click me</div>').appendTo(linkList);
link.click(function () {
    alert("I'm here");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your newly added div a class like this:

```
linkList.append('<div class="link">click me</div>');
```

Since your div has been dynamically created, you need to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to attach click event to this newly added div:

```
$(document).on('click', '.link', function() {
    alert("I'm here");
    return false;
});
```